# ui:inputSelect set the value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have ui:inputSelect with aura id. I am trying to set the value using aura id from controller.

```
 <td data-label="Learning Community" title="Learning Community">                            
                                <ui:inputSelect aura:id="lcapply" class="slds-input"
                                                labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!n.Learning_Community__c}">            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Learning Community..."/>
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.lcs}" var="lc">
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!lc.Id}" label="{!lc.Name}" />
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </ui:inputSelect>
                            </td>
```

Controller function:

```
onChangeLC : function(component,event,helper){
        var selectedLC = component.find("lc").get("v.value");        
        component.find("lcapply").set("v.value", selectedLC.toString());

        alert(selectedLC);
    }
```

I am getting this error, not sure what I am missing..:(

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
<aura:attribute name="lcselect" type="String" default="Select Learning Community..."/>   
 <td data-label="Learning Community" title="Learning Community">

                                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="lcapply" class="slds-input"
                                                    labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.lcselect}">            
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Learning Community..."/>
                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lcs}" var="lc">
                                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!lc.Id}" label="{!lc.Name}" />
                                        </aura:iteration>
                                    </ui:inputSelect>
                                </td>
```

Controller:

```
onChangeLC : function(component,event,helper){
        var selectedLC = component.find("lcValue").get("v.value");      
        component.set("v.lcselect", selectedLC.toString());    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a variable as you did with selectedLC, and then you can set a value by referencing the attribute.

The [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm) has a clear example on it:

```
({
    getLabel : function(component, event, helper) {
        var myLabel = component.find("button1").get("v.label");
        component.set("v.buttonLabel", myLabel);
    }
})
```

one more thing, make sure you have more than one element in your inputSelect list since there is this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BswQAE)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64925/discussion-on-answer-by-glls-uiinputselect-set-the-value).